# How to transform a dataframe with two categorical columns and their frequency in a new dataframe removing repeated information in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a R dataframe (29 rows and 3 columns) like this:

Role| Depression level| Frequency

Role has 6 categoriees (Others, Programmer, Tester, Architeect, Project Manager, Analyst).

Depression level has 5 categories (Minimal, Mild, Moderate, Moderate Severe, Severe).

Both categories have repetead values along the 29 roles. ex:

Role | Depression | Frequency

Other, Minimal, 4
Other, Mild, 6
Other, Moderate, 4
....

How can I generate a new dataframe with a structure like this (6 rows (for each role) x 6 columns:

Roles | Minimal | Mild | Moderate | Moderate Severe | Severe

Others, 5, 4, 6, 7, 2
Programmer, ...
Tester, ...
Architeect, ...
Project Manager, ...
Analyst ...

Thanks

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example:  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example> with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks, TarJae. I fixed that using a matrix:  
table(myDataFrame)

mat <-matrix(table(myDataFrame))